# How to set <asp:Panel> width to 25% of content size

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello can someone tell me how to give panel.width a 25% of content size?

Comment: Only on client side via JS script

Comment: can u tell me how? and give sample of js...

Comment: You want to make it with overflow?

Comment: how aboot setting the `Width` attribute (or CSS width property) to `25%`?

Comment: @Shai that would set it to 25% of its parent, rather than its content?

Comment: i'm not pro in javascript just wanna set this width to 25% css can't be used here...

Comment: Is it originally set in pixels or a %?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define Panel like this:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="CustomWidth" ID="MyPanel" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>
```

Then link to an external css stylesheet that set the following:

```
.CustomWidth{     width: 25%; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for that:

Assuming `Panel1` is the ID of your panel, and, the respective content container that you want to work according to is `Container1`,

```
var dWidth = $('#Container1').width();
$('#Panel1').width(dWidth * 0.25);
```

Will set `Panel1`'s width to 25% of the container you used.

Just decide which container you'd like to work with (could be a `div` or anything alike, you didn't show us your code)

Answer (score 0):

if you will not use JavaScript, you can write C# code in CodeBehind file:

`Panel1.Style.Add("width", "25%");`

Answer (score -1):

i dont really understand your Question but it's look like JavaScript Jobe,
for example:

```
var Element_Id = document.getElementById("Elem_Id"); // Element Id
var curr_Element_Width = parseInt(Element_Id.clientWidth); // parseInt is taking down our "px" string at the width.... look:
var curr_Element_Id_Width = 100px we need INT only!
we only need the number 100 so after parseInt its now 100 and not 100px we can't work with string's and that is the reson we doing that,
```

Then you can use function like this one...

```
function addWidth() {
    Element_Id.style.width = (curr_Element_Width + 100) + 'px'; // after we change the width we add the "px" string again
}
```

here we working with Px but you can do the same with % hope its will help you, have a nice day.